# Automatically test local javascript library on production page

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, automated-tests, test-framework

I would like to write an automatic test that goes on a production webpage which is using a specific library and replace it with the version I have on local.

This is useful for me to verify that when a new version of the library will be released to different pages they won't break (kind of smoke test).

For manual test atm I use [Requestly](http://www.requestly.in) to replace the host of the network request to that library, I'm wondering which would be the best test framework/approach to have an automatic test for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

### Upload/Share your rules to get a URL

1. Create Requestly Rule which you need in production and share it using [Requestly Share Rules feature](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/06/14/share-rules-with-other-users/). Once you share the rules, you will get a URL (say X). You can use the url to import the same rules at any other device.

### Use Selenium to install Requestly

2. Use Selenium to open Chrome Browser, Install [Requestly](https://www.requestly.in/) from [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa).
3. Open https://app.requestly.in/rules/ in a tab via Selenium script

### Load the Rules

4. Open url X (Obtained in Step 1) and use selenium script to click on "Import List" button.

### Run Automation Tests

5. Now, you have the rules in your chrome. Use the same selenium session to run your automation tests.

Please note that you have to repeat Steps 1-4 everytime you open a new chrome instance using Selenium (or any other framework). It may increase your automation suite running time a bit but atleast it achieves what you want.